require can't find file that do exist
I'm setting up Emacs on a work laptop with my old config file. And I have problem installing Copilot.
I cloned the repo in ~/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el directory:
I've added:
(add-to-list 'load-path "/home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el")

(require 'copilot)

And got an error:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "f")
  require(f)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-752679> nil "/home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el/copilot.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1818
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el/copilot.el" "/home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el/copilot.el" nil t)
  require(copilot)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/jakub/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 16353
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/jakub/.emacs" "/home/jakub/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x16b04b476c29>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x16b04b476c3d>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()

when I copy the path in the error and type in terminal
$ file "/home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el/copilot.el"
/home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el/copilot.el: ASCII text
~$ ls -lh /home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/
total 4,0K
drwxrwxr-x 5 jakub jakub 4,0K kwi 15 16:32 copilot.el
~$ ls -lh /home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el/
total 84K
drwxrwxr-x 2 jakub jakub 4,0K kwi 15 16:32 assets
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jakub jakub  14K kwi 15 16:32 copilot-balancer.el
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jakub jakub  44K kwi 15 16:32 copilot.el
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jakub jakub  566 kwi 15 16:32 Eask
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jakub jakub 1,1K kwi 15 16:32 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jakub jakub 9,5K kwi 15 16:32 README.md

Why I get this error? This never happen before.
I have Ubuntu  and I don't have SeLinux installed.

The error is:
(file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "f")

For the backtrace:
  require(f)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-752679> nil "/home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el/copilot.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1818
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el/copilot.el" "/home/jakub/projects/emacs-modes/copilot.el/copilot.el" nil t)
  require(copilot)
  [...]

I.e. Your problem is not that Emacs didn't find your copilot.el file.  Your problem is that copilot.el has called (require 'f) and Emacs didn't find f.el.
